# Does react form input need to be sanitized when sending emails with NodeMailer?

Tags: reactjs, security, input, nodemailer, sanitization

I see a lot of questions asking about sanitation for HTML, which React seems to do by default in JSX.  However, I've noticed this means it only sanitizes data being displayed back in the DOM.

In my situation I will be taking the form input straight away to a backend service to send an email (Looking at using NodeMailer).  The info about this is hard to find due to the sheer amount of info about the former situation above.  Even the info I see about my inquiry, I see mixed info.  Some people say it's not necessary if your just sending emails, other people (myself included) think that it should be sanitized.

So first question: For this scenario, is sanitation recommended?

Second Question: I see that NodeMailer lists "security" as one of their big perks, does NodeMailer already sanitize it's input?

Thanks for the input!